# Gentoo is missing X bitmapped fonts Helvetica, Times, Georgia

Tags: x11, fonts, gentoo, emerge, x

I'm installing Gentoo for the first time and I've noticed that all bitmapped X fonts except Misc are missing. For instance, I type

```
xlsfonts | grep -i helvetica
```

and it is not there, nor is times, georgia etc.

I have read that I need to "eset xft" in order to enable the installation of these fonts, but what is the emerge command for installing the fonts?

I don't mind manually downloading the PCF or BDF files from another distro but I don't think that should be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check the [Gentoo package site](https://packages.gentoo.org/categories/media-fonts), which has better indexing than the ebuilds.  For instance, it mentions that [liberation-fonts](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/media-fonts/liberation-fonts) can give the styles that you are asking for.

The "Adobe" fonts in most distributions provide Helvetica and Times Roman bitmap fonts:

- [media-fonts/font-adobe-100dpi](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/media-fonts/font-adobe-100dpi)
- [media-fonts/font-adobe-75dpi](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/media-fonts/font-adobe-75dpi)

but that doesn't include [Georgia](https://www.fonts.com/font/microsoft-corporation/georgia) (a Microsoft font).  Gentoo's index only lists that as a TrueType font.

Comment: The X11 BDF and PCF font files aren't related to Liberation fonts.